# What are the best ways to do field-wise datatype operations?

Tags: haskell

Say I have a datatype like:

```
data CpuStatRow a = CpuStatRow
  { user :: a
  , nice :: a
  , system :: a
  , idle :: a
  , ioWait :: a
  , irq :: a
  , softIrq :: a
  , steal :: a
  }
```

which comes from parsing CPU info from [/proc/stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) of a linux OS, in which every numeric field is an accumulative value since boot time. So if I want to figure out values during certain period, I need to grab `before :: CpuStatRow Int` and `after :: CpuStatRow Int` and do the field-wise difference (assuming proper language extensions):

```
-- let's not worry about distinction between a raw value and a difference for now ...
type Diff = Int
getDiff :: CpuStatRow Int -> CpuStatRow Int -> CpuStatRow Diff
getDiff after before = CpuStatRow {..}
  where
    diffOn prj = prj after - prj before
    user = diffOn user
    nice = diffOn nice
    ... -- basically same for each field
```

I'm wondering is there something better to do that:

- generalize to function of other aritieis (e.g. lift a function `f :: a -> b -> c -> d` to some `f' :: F a -> F b -> F c -> F d`
- can easily work on any datatype, as there are many accumulative values in `/proc`, applying the same method above is not fun. I have `Applicative` in mind but that doesn't seems to be "deriving-able" by ghc

Comment: wouldn't it make sense modelling the CpuStateRow using Map?

Comment: @ƛƛƛ but that'll impose an extra lookup overhead that I don't necessarily need - I already know all fields and there's no adding / removing of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to generalize to functions of any arity and any argument type, I think Applicative is the best you will find. Indeed you won't be able to derive it, but at least you can implement `pure` and `(<*>)` once and then reuse it for all of your functions rather than having to do the tedium for each of them. And you can ask GHC to derive the Functor instance for you, if nothing else.

If you want to work with "accumulative values" instead of general functions, you could consider adding a Monoid (or just Semigroup) instance, of the form

```
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (CpuStatRow a) where
  (CpuStatRow x y z ...) <> (CpuStatRow x' y' z') = CpuStatRow (x <> x') (y <> y') (z <> z') ...
```

As you can imagine that would get tiring quickly, but fortunately you can implement it in terms of Applicative - we're already saving time!

```
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (CpuStatRow a) where
  (<>) = liftA2 (<>)

instance Monoid a => Monoid (CpuStatRow a) where
  mempty = pure mempty
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! perhaps a bit off topic but I'm wondering if I can write Applicative instances with template haskell?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible for a type as regular as this, but I don't think enough people are writing a ton of types equivalent to `(a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a)` that this would be built into any library without having to do some work yourself.